# managing data access / user permissions

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-permissions

I am building a data structure designed for users to share information with friends based on permissions lists (friends or friend-list).

What is most best/efficient method for keeping access permissions for user data up-to-date for access by friends (or friend-list)?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read-up about the `offline_access` permission.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

With this permission, you'll be able to query facebook for information about one of your users even when that user is offline.  It gives you a "long living" access token.  This token does expire after a while or if the user changes his/her facebook password.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into the Facbook Realtime API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

You can subscribe to different user fields (e.g. user.friends), and whenever these fields update, FB hit your server. It doesn't say whether you can subscribe to user.friendlists or not, but it would be worth a try.

With regards to the answer from Lix; the offline_access permission is being deprecated. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/